# GIF from SRC folder in React project not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which should display a gif from the `"/src/images"` folder. Unfortunately that doesn't happen. I only get my "old" value displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Danke.js site:

```
import Confetti from "../images/confetti.gif";

<Box sx={{ justifyContent: "center", display: "flex" }}>
  <img
    src={Confetti}
    alt="Danke"
    width={"50%"}
    style={{ borderRadius: "50%", border: "7px solid black" }}
  />
</Box>
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: You are showing the HTML here not the actual render. Could be a CSS issue.

Comment: You're looking at your DOM, it says it's trying to load from `./static/media/` so: did you actually make sure that your build step copies your `/images` content to whatever directory the server uses for that? Also: [don't post images of code](/help/how-to-ask). Just copy that HTML from the DOM inspector and put that in your post.

Comment: What do u mean ?

Answer (score 0):

The image file is a local asset within the app, use `require` to access the local asset and pass to the `src` attribute. Note that this is different than using a normal path string to an asset in the built public directory.

```
<img
  src={require("../images/confetti.gif")}
  alt="Danke"
  width={"50%"}
  style={{ borderRadius: "50%", border: "7px solid black" }}
/>
```

or

```
const Confetti = require("../images/confetti.gif");

<Box sx={{ justifyContent: "center", display: "flex" }}>
  <img
    src={Confetti}
    alt="Danke"
    width={"50%"}
    style={{ borderRadius: "50%", border: "7px solid black" }}
  />
</Box>
```

Comment: No, that still doesn't work. I wonder why I have another gif which is in the same folder but I'm rendering in a different component. This is loaded and displayed without problems. However, I load this gif in another component and only get the alt attribute displayed, without any error codes in the console.

Comment: @Captai-N I see. So you are saying that another component is importing and rendering the `basket.gif` without issue? Could you try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?